# Problem with \includegraphics in beamer  -- greek language doesn't work

Tags: beamer

I use this code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\graphicspath{{/home/user/images/}}

\begin{document}


\section{intro}
\subsection{intro1}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{figure}

    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{imag1}

\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

and get 100 errors. The problem lies with `\includegraphics`; if I remove it it's OK. (The image is PNG and it is working with this layout in LaTeX.)

Is there some conflict with `babel`?

**---------------UPDATED----------------------------------------**

I noticed that in kile settings at the build section at the PDFLatex ,even though i had it to "xelatex" it showed "pdflatex" ,so i changed it again and now it works  **BUT** now the greek language doesn't work!I can't see anything greek.I haven't changed anything!

**--------------------UPDATED 2-----------------------------------------**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\gr}{\greektext}
\newcommand{\EN}{\latintext}

\begin{document}

Καλημέρα
\section{Ημέρα}

Καθόλου ελληνικά

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

Καλησπέρα

\EN English \gr

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No error here. What's the first error message?

Comment: @egreg:Hello,it shows "Missing $ inserted \end{frame}","Missing { inserted \end{frame}".It shows them a lot of times,also shows " Use of \\ifbeamercolorempty doesn't match its definition \end{frame}".All the errors vanish if i remove "includegraphics".Thanks

Comment: @egreg:Hello , i updated...

Comment: Does `\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{imag1.png}` solve the problem?

Comment: You mustn't use `inputenc` with XeLaTeX and `babel` with Greek doesn't work. Use Polyglossia.

Comment: @ egreg: Hello , 1) i used that so long and i didn't have problems  2) i tried with polyglossia but it doesn't work in beamer,only in latex! Thanks.  (i repeat , i haven't changed a thing,everything worked fine and suddenly everything not work)

Comment: If I run XeLaTeX on your code I don't get any error. Please make an example that shows the problem.

Comment: @egreg : It just doesn't show greek language at all.. (with babel,the above example,which worked fine yesterday!) (with polyglossia i get a lot of errors)

Comment: It's useless to continue talking about Greek when the example has no Greek at all.

Comment: @egreg:I updated..The english language works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The updated example *can't* work with XeLaTeX. Here's a version that works

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\begin{document}

Καλημέρα
\section{Ημέρα}

Καθόλου ελληνικά

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

Καλησπέρα

English

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Check the documentation of Polyglossia for the environments and commands that deal with language changes (they are not so important for `beamer`, as hyphenation shouldn't be used and `\raggedright` is in force).

Comment: :Ok , it works with \setsansfont{DejaVuSans}. I still can't understand why suddenly stopped to work.Any way..Thank you very much!